# Which database design is better?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I am about to create a database to track weight-lifting exercises.

Which approach would you prefer?

**Solution A:**

Two tables

> - Exercise (with ID, Name etc.)
> - Set (with ID, Set_Number, Date, FK_Exercise)

Here, one `Exercise` and `Set` have a one-to-many relationship.
`Set_Number` is supposed to track which set it is on a given date (1st set, 2nd set, 3rd set etc.)

Advantage: One table less to deal with.

**Solution B:**

Three tables:

> - Exercise (with ID, Name etc.)
> - Session (with ID, Date, FK_Exercise)
> - Set (with ID, Set_Number, FK_Session)

Here, a `Session` would be something like a connector between `Exercise` and `Set`. So basically a sequence of sets on a given day for a given exercise will be pooled in one `Session` instance.
In this case, `Exercise` and `Session` have a one-to-many relationship and `Session` and `Set` also have a one-to-many relationship.

Advantage: The Date property will not be redundant for any given day. And logically it makes sense to bundle sets.

Comment: Please provide sample data.  Can a set consist of more than one exercise?  What is a session?  Does it consist of multiple sets?  Is it important (it is not in the first data model)?

Comment: Start by identifying as many business requirements as you can, and design your database to satisfy those.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Question edited. Better now?

Comment: "One table less to deal with." is not something I would consider as an advantage.

Comment: You *must* provide two things: dependencies and the level of normalization you wish to achieve. Don't fall into the trap of looking at data that might go in the tables.

Comment: @nicomp - but how would you determine the correct dependencies and normalization *without* "looking at data"??? Surely looking at the data is the basis of data modelling (the clue is in the name).

Comment: @APC When you start looking at data to determine dependencies you fool yourself. Give me any nontrivial dataset and dependencies you've derived from that data: I will add one record and blow up your dependencies. Sample data is useful as a starting point for discussions but that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good data model falls out of a proper understanding of the domain. Your domain has three entities:

- EXERCISE: particular type of weightlifting move (*name* and *weight*)
- SET: number of *reps* of a given EXERCISE (depending on training goal - strength, muscle, endurance?)
- SESSION: number of SETs undertaken on a given *date*

So you need at least three tables. At least, because EXERCISE has two levels of detail: one is the exercise *name* and the other is the exercise *weight* . It's quite likely you will need to store SETs of different combination of names and weights (`Bicep curl / 10kg`, `Bicep curl / 15kg`, etc) in which case you need a look-up table EXERCISE name and a fourth table SET_EXERCISE to store the weight used for a particular SET of *reps*.

Having gone through this exercise (o ho!) we can see that your foreign keys are wrong. A SESSION comprises a number of SETs; a SET comprises a number of EXERCISEs (SET_EXERCISEs).

Hence the logical data model should look something like:

- EXERCISE (ID, Name, Weight, etc)
- SET (ID, FK_Exercise, Reps, etc)
- SESSION (ID, FK_Set, Date, etc)

Although this is not quite accurate: SET:SESSION is in fact a many-to- many relationship, as a SESSION will normally comprise more than one SET and a SET can be done in more than one SESSION.

When it comes to a physical data model i.e. tables you should have five tables:

- EXERCISE (ID, Name, etc)
- SET_EXERCISE (ID, FK_Exercise, FK_Set, Weight, etc)
- SET (ID, FK_Set_Exercise, Reps, etc)
- SESSION_SET (FK_Set, FK_Session, Set_Number, etc)
- SESSION (ID, Date, etc)

The SESSION_SET table is necessary to resolve the many-to-many relationship between SET and SESSION .

The final model has five tables: three tables for the original entities and two intersection tables which join those entities. It so happens that all the relations between the logical entities (EXERCISE, SET, SESSION) have been implemented as intersection tables rather than foreign keys. This doesn't always happen when transforming from a Logical to a Physical data model.

---

This is not the only way of modelling the domain. As a design activity data modelling is about [interpreting the rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to fit the data you need to record. The data is the starting point.

> "it seems I didn't make myself clear regarding the *Session* entity...he naming is probably bad and misleading"

This is why I said the data model follows from **a proper understanding of the domain**. EXERCISE, SET and SESSION are domain terms. You are of course welcome to make your own definitions of things for your private projects, but in real life data models are a mechanism for communication between Development and Business: the meaning of things is crucial, and must conform to a common understanding. We cannot build a data model where SESSION means something different from what the business understands by *"session"*.

> "I also don't understand how a *Set* can be done in more than one *Session*?"

A SET is a pattern of EXERCISE for a number of *reps*. So `#1 / benchpress / 130KG / 8 reps` is a SET and `#2 / benchpress / 100KG / 12 reps` is a different SET. If you benchpressed 130KG eight times on Monday and Wednesday then that's the same SET in two different SESSIONs. Maybe it's a layer of detail too far; but if you're going to build a database app to track your workouts instead of using a spreadsheet like most people you might as well build the best data model you can :-)

Again, data modelling is an exercise with a large dose of opinion: if your data model is good enough for your current needs then it is good enough. The thing is, a more rigorous data model is paradoxically more flexible (because enforcing data integrity rules makes it easier to write queries and be sure that the results are correct). What might be good enough now might be a terrible brake on innovation in the future.

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time! However, it seems I didn't make myself clear regarding the _Session_ entity. It is not supposed to be ALL sets of a given day but only the sets of ONE given _Exercise_ on a given day (the naming is probably bad and misleading). Also, wouldn't it be best to add the weight to the _Set_ entity? And I also don't understand how a _Set_ can be done in more than one _Session_? A _Set_ can not be stretched to two days, can it?